# bloomberg: how to use ticker to return ISIN

Tags: excel, api, bloomberg

I've been using Datastream and Bloomberg to collect data. First I've got a large sample of **bond** ISIN from datastream, then in order to get the corresponding firm financials, I use bloomberg function `=BDP(A1&"@BGN Corp", "Issuer_parent_eqy_ticker")`, A1 being the ISINs, to get the equity ticker number. This will return the ticker number. 
Now I need the equity (stock) information of that firm, preferably ISIN.
Now the question is, can I use the ticker number to return equity ISINs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `ID_ISIN` to pull Issuer ISIN using Issuer ticker, for example:

Bond: `DD103619@TRAC Corp`

```
=BDP(BDP("DD103619@TRAC Corp","ISSUER_PARENT_EQY_TICKER") & " Equity", "ID_ISIN")
```

returns: `US4592001014` which is ISIN of IBM US Equity

Comment: Hi.
Is there a way to turn an equity ticker to ISIN? For example, given AMZN US Equity, can I turn into ISIN?

Comment: =BDP("AMZN US Equity", "ID_ISIN")

Will display the ISIN identifier for "AMZN US Equity".

Comment: Note, this only works if you have a license for the pricing source.  In this case, `@TRAC`. It could also be `@BGN`, etc.