# Convert tIckers bloomberg into ISIN

Tags: bloomberg, isin

I have a large list of bloomberg tickers  for BE500 Index

but I need the ISIN or CUSIPS...
How can I get it?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36512232/829571

Comment: How are you accessing Bloomberg? Terminal, Excel, Python, COM, C++,R .... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on excel with the Bloomberg extension, try

```
=BQL(A1,"ID_ISIN")
```

Where cell `A1` is your ticker.

Comment: BDP is the function, I think.

Comment: Both BDP and BQL work in this case.