# How to add ISIN to excel?

Tags: bloomberg

I'm trying to pull the ISIN Data from bloomberg to excel automatically. Is there a forumla I can use? I have the asset name and cusip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert tIckers bloomberg into ISIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458339/convert-tickers-bloomberg-into-isin)